# How to create an app server with Node JS and send HTTP Request for FCM

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

After searching a lot, I could not really find what I was looking for. I am trying to send a HTTP request to firebase cloud messaging but I need it to send real time to a user on a website when there are some changes made to things the user is subscribed to. After research it looks like I need to send it through an app server. I have never created an app server so could anyone help on how I could create this for my situation? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use cloud functions for that?

Comment: Specifically, have a look at this [use-case in the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens) or this [blog post for a more verbose explanation of the process](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html).

Comment: Would cloud functions work for web notifications? I read it was for android device to an android device.